# Why aren't the fabric squares on the corner of a woolen tzitzis garment made of wool?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

Is someone wants to wear a wool garment for his tzitzis garment, shouldn't the fabric squares on the corner of a woolen tzitzis garment also be made from wool ? [It doesn't seem to me that the common wool garments have patches made of wool.]

The reason we place patches on the corner, is because if some would make an entire garment out of small patches [less than 3 fingers by 3 fingers], at least the corners would be a patches that are the correct size [(see here)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9429/why-do-tzitzit-have-fabric-squares-on-the-corners-of-the-garment). If so, shouldn't the patch also be made out of the preferred wool material?

Comment: Just a guess, but that concern practically doesn't exist these days so seemingly no one cares to be careful about wool corner-patches, especially since needing wool at all is at best a chumra. (Assuming the size thing is really the original reason for the custom of reinforcing the corners.) You're essentially asking manufacturers to do something with no halakhic benefit for an outlandish case where worst case you still fulfill the mitzva, albeit not in the best way according to a minority opinion.